# Favicon doesn't work on edge

Tags: html, favicon, microsoft-edge

I have a favicon in a website that it works in all browsers, except of Microsoft Edge. What's the issue?

My code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
```

I have also tried with `type="image/x-icon"`.

Comment: did you hit fn F5 to refresh the cache?

Comment: I also tried, but it disn't work

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it seems as though favicon will only worked after you have deployed your site and never on localhost.

Try deploying the site to see if it works.

Comment: I use xampp server, I have to run the website in the servers?

Comment: Are you hosting your site online or in an intranet? 
Also, be sure that your favicon is in the same directory as your index.html file

Comment: It doesn't work if the link of the favicon is like this?: ../img/favicon.ico

Comment: Apparently not from what I've seen doing a bit of research. Leave it in the same directory as your index.html and try